# How to aggregation the result of other aggregation in elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

In this question, I get a confuse here that how could I do aggregate the result from other aggregation?
Here is my first bucket result：

```
{
  "took" : 2,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 35,
    "successful" : 35,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 864,
    "max_score" : 0.0,
    "hits" : [ ]
  },
  "aggregations" : {
    "group_by_uid" : {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count" : 240,
      "buckets" : [
        {
          "key" : "18133455169",
          "doc_count" : 110
        },
        {
          "key" : "15736767693",
          "doc_count" : 100
        },
        {
          "key" : "17354023823",
          "doc_count" : 76
        },
        {
          "key" : "18119669395",
          "doc_count" : 76
        },
        {
          "key" : "18119772327",
          "doc_count" : 56
        },
        {
          "key" : "18156993756",
          "doc_count" : 52
        },
        {
          "key" : "18727508556",
          "doc_count" : 46
        },
        {
          "key" : "18895657556",
          "doc_count" : 45
        },
        {
          "key" : "18605910769",
          "doc_count" : 42
        },
        {
          "key" : "13182871522",
          "doc_count" : 21
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

and here is my first query DSL：

```
GET /dailyactiveindex-*/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  }, 
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "group_by_uid": {
      "terms": {"field": "userId.keyword"}
    }
  }
}
```

Now I wanna aggragate the result from first bucket, and count the `doc_count` which it is same.

Goal is that I wanna reach:

```
{'buckets': [{'key': '110', 'doc_count': 1},
    {'key': '100', 'doc_count': 1},
    {'key': '76', 'doc_count': 2},
    {'key': '56', 'doc_count': 1},
    {'key': '52', 'doc_count': 1},
    {'key': '46', 'doc_count': 1},
    {'key': '45', 'doc_count': 1},
    {'key': '42', 'doc_count': 1},
    {'key': '21', 'doc_count': 1}]}
```

Thank you!

Comment: This can easily be achieved with a [`scripted_metric` aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-scripted-metric-aggregation.html). Can you try it out first?

Comment: Thanks man! I already did it by using `scripted_metric aggregation`, Thanks again!!

Comment: Nice, you should post your answer as that could help other people with the same need ;-)

Comment: Yes...Im arranging my answer and post it after

Comment: In fact, I haven't totaly achieve my goal, because my field `userId` is `text` not `keyword` which makes wrong, but the thought is right, and the such circumstances can use my post demo to solve it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
{
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  }, 
  "size": 1000,
  "aggs": {
    "intersect": {
      "scripted_metric": {
        "init_script": "state.map=[:]",
        "map_script": "state.map[doc.userId.value]=1",
        "combine_script": "return state.map",
        "reduce_script": "return states"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure you need to increment the counter at some point, otherwise you're not counting the occurrences, and hence, cannot order them the way you described

Comment: yeah, you're right, it just a demo and now Im trying to transfer field `userId` from `text` to `keyword`, otherwise getting wrong that `Fielddata is disabled on text fields by default. Set fielddata=true on [userId] in order to load fielddata in memory by uninverting the inverted index. Note that this can however use significant memory. Alternatively use a keyword field instead.`, which needs `reindex`, I will finish this demo after